# Can we say a Markov Chain with only isolated states is time reversible?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

By "isolated", I mean that each state of this Markov Chain has 0 probability to move to another state, i.e. transition probability $p_{ij} = 0$ for $ i \ne j$.  Thus, there isn't a unique stationary distribution.

But by definition, since for any stationary distribution $\pi$, we have

$$
\pi_{i}p_{ij} = 0 = \pi_{j}p_{ji}
$$

seems that we can still call this Markov Chain time reversible.

Is the concept "time reversible" still make sense in this situation?

---

A bit background, I was asked to find a Markov Chain, with certain restrictions, that is NOT time reversible.  But I found if the stationary distribution exist, the chain is always reversible.  So I guess that my be chance is that a chain who doesn't have unique stationary distribution.  Maybe in this situation we can't call the chain reversible.

Comment: I am confused about one point. Are you defining a single isolated state i.e., $p_{ij}=0$ for *exactly one* $i$ with $i \ne j$ or is it that $p_{ij}=0$ for every $i \ne j$? If the latter, you really do not have a markov chain anymore as the states do not change at all.

Comment: That depends on the precise definition of Markov chain.  As far as I can see, it's still one chain, just one with special transition probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Markov chain is reversible --- you've shown it yourself by showing that the detailed balance equation holds.

You can show that the detailed balance condition is equivalent to:

1. $p_{ij}>0\Rightarrow p_{ji}>0$
2. For every cycle $i_0,i_1,\dots,i_n,i_0$ in the set of states, the probability of 'going' in the cycle $i_0\rightarrow i_0$ is equal for clockwise and anticlockwise orientations.

Thus, you could say that your Markov chain is vacuously reversible as there are no cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that constructing a markov chain with isolated states will give you a time irreversible markov chain.

Consider the case when you have one isolated state. Since, an isolated state can never be reached from any other state, your chain is actually a union of two different markov chains.

1. A markov chain that always stays in the isolated state (which is time reversible by definition) and
2. A markov chain on the non-isolated states which may or may not be time reversible.

Thus, I do not think the above strategy will work.